# Mongo DB Service is stopped automatically on frequent basis from Services

Tags: mongodb, service

Mongo DB is called in every 1 minute to insert data. and in between this process, the Mongo DB service is auto-stopped frequently.

Comment: Hi Sweta! Can you send the log output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.